# Searching between Two Date Fields

Tags: mongodb, date

Let's say I have this document structure:

```
{ 
  "event" : "Event 1"
  "startDate": 20130101, // Jan-1-2013
  "endDate": 20140101 // Jan-1-2014
}
```

How can I search for all documents with a date falling between the `startDate` and `endDate` **making use of indexing**?

> Example: find all documents that fall between 20120101 and 20150101.

My above document should match since 20130101 to 20140101 falls between the above query.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Surely some of the [Mongodb comparison query operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/nav-query/#comparison) will be helpful...

Comment: @maerics, with my data set, my working assumption is that, unless I can fully take advantage of indexing (which I'm not sure how to do in my 'search between 2 dates), then the results will be too slow. I'm curious whether indexing can help for the type of query I'm trying.

Comment: update your question with your concerns about indexing; they seem more relevant than the simple query syntax question that it appears to be now.

Comment: I'd always suggest using `explain` to see how the query is being executed.

Answer (score 1):

`db.coll.find({endDate : {$lt : 20150101}, startDate : {$gt : 20120101}}`

or use `$lte`, `$gte`

If it's a frequent query and a rather large collection, use index for start and end dates

Comment: For a 2-key compound index, my understanding is that the `exact` match needs to be the first key, and the second key should be the "range" parameter. In this case, both fields are ranges. This point leads to my reason for asking this question.

Comment: True, but as you had noted, you can't have exact match here. Ideally all index traversal will be done in memory w/o faults. It's usually not a burden compared to non index query especially for non wide ranges. The fact that you don't have to order (allegedly) is also crucial

Comment: Also, maerics is right, you should change the title to express your index concern